# How to customize ckeditor toolbar button behavior?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, right-to-left

In ckeditor 4.0.1 in when "text direction from left to right" toolbar button is pushed, i type `hello`, the generated HTML source is:

```
<p dir="ltr">hello</p>
```

how can i change this behavior so that the generated source is look like:

```
<p dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;">hello</p>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm really afraid but you need to write your own JS function which will apply stylesheet property to the required element and stop the current running script

Comment: Can you describe me more. How ?

Comment: Just a note, the css equivalent of dir=ltr is direction:ltr not text-align

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with dataProcessor:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    on: {
        instanceReady: function () {
            this.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules( {
                elements: {
                    p: function( element ) {
                        if ( element.attributes.dir == 'ltr' )
                            element.attributes.style = 'text-align: left;';
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
} );
```

You can also add it globally:

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function ( event ) {
    event.editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules( {
        elements: {
            p: function( element ) {
                if ( element.attributes.dir == 'ltr' )
                    element.attributes.style = 'text-align: left;';
            }
        }
    });
} );
```

Comment: @SaeedZarinfam `editor1` is an id of your editor instance. You know this identifier, don't you?

I'd rather include this in the script tag in your webpage than in config.js.

Yes, it'll work with 3.x.

Comment: Very nice your solution was great.